# Why does Canvas leave a ghostly ring?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm experimenting with Canvas, placing tokens of different colors on a grid, and trying to remove them.

I'm currently trying to remove the token by drawing a circle of the exact same dimensions in white over the token.  This is leaving a "ghostly ring" (single pixel outline) where the original circle was, that disappears with successive applications of the white circle.

[image: Ring example]

The circle in 2, -1 is originally drawn, and not at all overpainted.  The circle in 3, -1 has been overpainted once, the circle in 4, -1 has been overpainted twice, and so on to 7, -1.

This behavior occurs in both Chrome and Firefox 3.6

My code follows.

```
   function placeToken(e) {
        var click = getClick(e);

        var gridCord = getGridCord(click);

        var canvas = e.currentTarget;
        var ctx = canvas.getContext(CONTEXT_NAME);

        ctx.fillStyle = color;
        ctx.strokeStyle = color; //tried with and without this line, no effect

        x = (gridCord.x * spacing) + (spacing / 2);
        y = (gridCord.y * spacing) + (spacing / 2);


        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(x, y, (spacing - tokenEdge) / 2, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.stroke();  //tried with and without this line.  Same result
    };
```

Why does canvas leave this Ghostly ring, and how can I get rid of it?

Comment: it's very well known by flash developers that canvas is haunted

Comment: In short, antialiasing. The pixels on the edge of that circle are being painted with less than 100% opacity. This isn't unique to canvas. You just have to paint over it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In short, antialiasing. The pixels on the edge of that circle are being painted with less than 100% opacity. This isn't unique to canvas. Back in the day, Windows applications written and tested before Windows graphics APIs did antialiasing would leave ghostly boundaries when run on versions of Windows that did antialiasing.

You just have to paint a completely opaque white rectangle over it. Since a rectangle doesn't have curved edges, every pixel will be either completely painted white or unaffected -- you won't get antialiasing.

Comment: Actually, you could still see anti-aliasing problems if the rectangle is drawn on [non-pixel boundaries](http://diveintohtml5.org/canvas.html#pixel-madness). This might easily occur when dividing a region into a number of squares, or with stroking.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like [anti-aliasing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-aliasing), the technique of minimizing the distortion artifacts known as aliasing when representing a high-resolution image at a lower resolution. As a circle is high-resolution until drawn you will get these bleeding effects.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't messed with canvas much, but I figure the problem occurs for the same reason it does in Photoshop.

When you draw a circle, it has to be antialiased to prevent jagged edges from being visible.  This means you end up with pixels all around the circle that are semi-transparent to varying degrees, in order to achieve smoothness.

When you paint over top of the circle using the same position and dimensions, it's essentially painting semi-transparent pixels on top of already semi-transparent pixels, leaving you with a ring of pixels that is close to the original color (but slightly lighter). That is why the more times you draw the white circle the closer it comes to a fully white block.